# Avoid counting comments in code

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, comments

I'm trying to count all chars in a string, except for any comments.
The goal is to be able to write in all my code in an input field, and then get a total amount of chars excluding all comments (entire lines after "//")

This is what i got so far:

```
 function findComments() {
    var string = document.getElementById("input").innerText;
    var splittedString = string.split("");
    var totalComments = "";
    var count = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < splittedString.length; i++) {
        if (splittedString[i]+splittedString[i+1] == "//") {
           console.log("found");
        } else {
            count++;
        }
    }
    console.log(count);
}
```

My code so far counts all chars including the lines after //, but the loops works and it logs out "found" after all the "//"

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you describe what is your goal and more context

Comment: the goal is to copy alot of code into an input field, and then count all chars without counting the comments

Comment: Your code does not consider things like `var string="Some // text";` You'll need a state machine

Comment: well the string text comes from an input field "input"

Comment: Algorithm:  try to remove all characters in range from '//' to '\n'. Then just count number of characters in processed string

Comment: Exactly Andy, but how do i achieve this? i guess its done by removing it from the splitted array, and then joining it all together again?

Comment: to test for `//`, just test `splittedString[i + 1]` (if index i+1 exists), if `splittedString[i]` is already `/`.

Comment: Ah Kaddath nice solution to the double //, thanks

Comment: Is there any1 who have got a solution to how i can make it NOT count, from // all the way up until it reaches \n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by removing all comments and then counting characters.

```
function main() {
    var code = "var x = 0; // this is comment \n print(x)\n";

    var result = removeComments(code)
    console.log(result)
    // Result: var x = 0; \n print(x)\n
    console.log(result.length)
    // Result: 20
}
function removeComments(code) {
    var result = code
    while (true) {
       var commentIndex = result.indexOf("//");
       var endOfStringIndex = result.indexOf("\n");
       // return from function if no // or \n found in code
       if (commentIndex == -1 || endOfStringIndex == -1) { return result; }
       result = result.replace(result.substring(commentIndex, endOfStringIndex+2), "");
    }
}
```